# How to display bootstrap modal using anchor tag

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to call `modal` using anchor tag...
Here's the `HTML` code

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
   <span class="dropdown-header">
      <i class="far fa-user-circle"></i>
      <a class="nav-link" name='viewProfile' href="studenthome.php?viewProfile=true" data-widget="control-sidebar"
      data-slide="true" role="button"><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></a>
   </span>
   <span class="dropdown-header bg-danger font-weight-bold">                        
     <a class="nav-link" name='deleteAccount' style="color: #fff" href="studenthome.php?deleteAccount=true" data-widget="control-sidebar" data-slide="true" role="button" data-toggle="modal" id="pop-over" data-target="#exampleModal">Delete Account</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Above code is inside the **navbar** and when I click on the **Delete Account** I want to pop over my modal and here is my modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can please help me to call the modal class when I click on **Delete Account** link.
Thankyou in advance

Comment: I can't see any problems in your code, it should work. [ref](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Comment: But it's not working when I click on the link Mr @AhmedTagAmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="far fa-user"></i> Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="far fa-user"></i> Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item text-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i> Delete Account</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the HTML you supplied the dropdown was not appearing at all for me. I had to add a toggle in order to make it work:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
</button>
```

From then on I didn't have problem opening the modal, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha14jLgx/). I'm not familiar with PHP though and how it would play with href attribute you added for the delete button. This is from [bootstrap's dropdown docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/).